# Facebook story text is missing

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have an Android app that publishes custom actions like this "*USER_NAME* purchased an item on *APP_NAME*". Posting the action from both my app and the Graph Explorer completes successfully.

The problem is when I go to my Activity Log the actions appear without text. I see only the items' picture and link while yesterday I was seeing also the desired text.

Answer (score 0):

I's not a problem with your app.
Seems like a recent bug at facebook. Clear all your cache and check. In my case, the problem just shows at Chrome.